# AMDGPU-Pro Ubuntu 16.04 - R9 390 identified as R9 290, low performance, and graphical artefacts

Tags: drivers, 16.04, games, amd-graphics, visual-artifacts

I am trying to leave Windows behind, and at this moment I am simply using Wine to play games. Later I will do a GPU Passthrough in a Virtual Machine.

I am aware that AMDGPU was expected not to support GCN1.1 hardware. However, the url https://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMD-Radeon-GPU-PRO-Linux-Beta-Driver%E2%80%93Release-Notes.aspx shows the R9 390 as supported.

Does anyone know if it has been modified to in fact support 1.1 hardware?

The command `sudo lshw -c video` displays: `configuration: driver=amdgpu latency=0` and I have installed AMDGPU-PRO from AMD.

However, `lspci | grep -i VGA` shows:

`01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc. [AMD/ATI] Hawaii PRO [Radeon R9 290] (rev 80)`

I am using a R9 390, I confirmed this by taking the side panel off my computer and reading the sticker that says 390, not 290. I don't know what's wrong here and if it's affecting my performance.

Currently in World of Warcraft I get 30 fps, whereas on Windows I get upwards of 100 fps.

So question 1 is how can I get my OS to identify my GPU correctly?

My second question is I get white artefacts across the screen every few seconds, they are simple white lines in random positions. This does not happen if I am not using AMDGPU-PRO.

Does anyone know the cause and fix? Thanks.

Comment: I'm in the same situation.  I have tried a variety of kernels with both `radeon` and `amdgpu`, and settled on 4.4 with `amdgpu`.   Even though lspci report the card as a 290, other programs (such as dolphin) report it as a 390.  FWIW: I get incredible performance using the Vulkan API w/ The Talos Principle.  Maybe that's a sign of better things to come.

Comment: @JustinMylesHolmes that's interesting you settled on 4.4 with amdgpu, did you compile the kernel yourself with the Enable CIK parts flag set?

Comment: No I didn't - I don't even know about that flag.  Can you link me to a place where I can learn more about what it might do in conjunction with this driver?  I have good notes on all the configs I have tried; I love the idea of finding one that *actually* works wonderfully (with OpenGL, not just Vulkan) and sharing that info.